# how to remove the lock in pycharm file?

Tags: python

[image]

There is a lock in the csv file icon, I don't know what it means. It's about 300 MB, and I can't load the whole file

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/locking-and-unlocking-files-and-folders.html):

> To unlock a file, select the file you want to unlock, or open it in
>   the editor, and choose VCS | Subversion | Unlock from the main menu,
>   or Subversion | Unlock from the context menu of the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can import **portalocker** and that looks like--

```
import portalocker
portalocker.unlock(fileName.csv)
```

for better understanding and more knowledge you may see this [link](http://portalocker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) .
Thanks.